# businessHours not working with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

The business hours not showing on my calendar as i want them to be, its showing only Monday-Friday while my **businessHours** list contains just Monday and Tuesday .

```
$scope.businessHours = [
    {
        start: "09:00",
        end: "19:00",
        dow: [1,2]
    }
]

$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
        header: $scope.calendarHeader,
        eventClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        events: $scope.bookings,
        select: $scope.select,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
        locale: 'ru',
        lang: 'ru',
        timezone: 'local',
        height: 680,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        navLinks: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        resizable: true,
        eventResize: false,
        minTime: "06:00:00",
        maxTime: "22:00:00",
        eventLimit: 6,
        unselectAuto: true,
        stick: true,
        selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
        businessHours: $scope.businessHours
    },
};
```

I am using **fullcalendar 2.7.3** and **AngularJS 1.6.9**.

Comment: So, what inside `$scope.businessHours`? Please include that object in the question

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add them in code , question updated!!

Comment: Yes, well the issue is that you're trying to pass an array instead of an object, you can either change it to `businessHours: $scope.businessHours[0]` or change the scope property to `$scope.businessHours = {start: "09:00", end: "19:00", dow: [1,2]};`

Comment: It worked :), thanks @AlonEitan for your interest and of course for your help , i would prefer to keep it as you mentioned above `businessHours: $scope.businessHours[0]`

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) Please [read this](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v291-2016-07-31): The option to have _multiple definitions for businessHours_ was added only in v2.9.1 so you need to upgrade your fullcalendar plugin to this version to be able to pass an array